# Hour deltatime mistake

Tags: python, datetime

```
now = datetime.now()
d1 = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, 0)

if now.minute in xrange(46, 60):
    res = 0
    print now.hour
    print now.hour+1
    d1 = d1 + timedelta(hours=now.hour+1)
    print d1
```

`now.hour` prints, for example, 15. Second line shows up `16` but `d1` after adding timedelta becomes: `2012-07-21 07:57:00`. This date is next day at 7am.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a timedelta with a value of 16 hours and then add that to d1. d1 (if already at 15 hours) plus 16 hours will be 07 hours the next day.

You don't say what you are trying to achieve but if you are trying to increment by one hour then you should use `d1 = d1 + timedelta(hours=1);`

Comment: Or, more succinctly, just `d1 += timedelta(hours=1)`